# ember-cli won't render from my model from the data store

Tags: ember.js, ember-data, ember-cli

I am using ember cli with ember data and have been piecing together information but it still doesn't work. This all involves the Home model, route and template. I feel like I'm close but still no cigar. I took everything out except for the title to simplify it. According to documentation I've read, everything is as it should be.

here is my app.js

```
import Ember from 'ember';
import Resolver from 'ember/resolver';
import loadInitializers from 'ember/load-initializers';
import config from './config/environment';

Ember.MODEL_FACTORY_INJECTIONS = true;

var App = Ember.Application.extend({
  modulePrefix: config.modulePrefix,
  podModulePrefix: config.podModulePrefix,
  Resolver: Resolver
});

loadInitializers(App, config.modulePrefix);

export default App;
```

Here is my home model:

```
 import DS from 'ember-data';

    export default DS.Model.extend({
    title         : DS.attr('string'),
    });

    Home.reopenClass({
    FIXTURES :[
    {
     id: 1,
     title: 'Sponge B',
    }, 

    {
    id: 2,
    title: 'John David',
    }, 

    ]
    });
```

Here is my home route:

```
    import Ember from 'ember';
    //import DS from 'ember-data';

    export default  Ember.Route.extend({
         model: function(){
            return this.store.find('Home');
        },
    });
```

This is my home template:

```
   <div id="home"> 
    {{#each}}
    <p>{{title}}</p>
    {{/each}}
   </div>
   {{outlet}}
```

Could someone please help me out?

I think it has something to do with my model hook.
Could this also be a controller issue. I generated a basic controller. Should I have generated an arrayController?. The home route when saved gives me this error message:
models/home.js: line 9, col 1, 'Home' is not defined. but when I define it there still is a problem. Am I supposed to ad  a folder called adapters, then put a file in it called application.js, then ad export default DS.FixtureAdapter.extend(); . But when I do that it tells me DS is not defined

Answer (score 0):

Your template seems to be the issue.  You reference an `item` property that isn't there:

```
<div id="home">
    {{#each}}
    <p>{{title}}</p>
    {{/each}}
</div>
```

Also, you have some syntax problems with your model.  Try this:

```
import DS from 'ember-data';

var Home= DS.Model.extend({
  title         : DS.attr('string'),
});

Home.reopenClass({
  FIXTURES :[
    {
     id: 1,
     title: 'Sponge B',
    }, 

    {
    id: 2,
    title: 'John David',
    }, 
  ]
});
export default Home;
```

Comment: that was a typo. Even when I change that. It still doesn't work

Comment: You should make the changes to your model as well.  You should have been seeing errors in the console when running your code, like `ReferenceError: Home is not defined`

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are explicitly exporting your model as `Home` and then you are trying to `find('home')` which does not have the same letter case.

Ember will not automatically resolve the case for you.  If you want to use `Home` as the model, you will need to call it in the same way every time.

You might even need to `import Home from '../models/model-file';` if you want to call it from the route..

An easier thing to try would be to use the implicit `export default Ember.Model.extend({})` and let ember-cli resolve the class using your file name.

http://www.ember-cli.com/#using-modules

Comment: in all the documentationsI have read and also in other programs I wrote, whatever is in the find method is not capitalized. If your fixture is Home.Products.FIXTURES. You don't find Products like this find('Products') it's find('products')

Answer (score 0):

For the Fixture Adapter you are correct in adding the application.js to the adapters folder and import DS from 'ember-data'.

Also in Steve H's example of your home model, the definition of the FIXTURES is not correct.  Try using:
Home.FIXTURES = [
...
];

Make sure the pathing is correct.